# Problema sql mostrar datos

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente sql en donde muestro dependiendo de la empresa lo que me esta generando problema que me trae los tecnicos de los contratistas

```
SELECT
   e.idtickets,
   e.empresa,
   e.status,
   e.tipo_ticket,
   e.cierre_ticket,

   t.idtickets,
   t.asigno,
   t.asignado,

   u.idusuario AS idusuario,
   u.nombre AS nombre_usuario,

   count(t.asignado) AS todos

     FROM tickets_asignado AS t

        LEFT JOIN tickets AS e ON e.idtickets = t.idtickets

        LEFT JOIN usuario AS u ON u.idusuario = t.asignado

    WHERE ((e.empresa='3' AND e.tipo_ticket='Propios' AND e.idtickets=t.idtickets AND e.status = '4' AND e.cierre_ticket BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-05-31') 

            OR 

          (e.empresa='3' AND e.tipo_ticket='Partner' AND e.idtickets=t.idtickets AND e.status = '4' AND e.cierre_ticket BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-05-31'))

    GROUP BY t.asignado
```

Como hago para eliminar lo que esta sombreado ya que no necesito mostrarlos

[image: imagen]

Comment: obviamente falta un where, pero por que reglas queres eliminarlos?

Comment: Es que los que dicen Contra .. Quiero mostrarlos solo quiero mostrar los que dicen "Tecnico 1 Empresa 2, Tecnico 2 Empresa 2, Tecnico 3 Empresa 3"

Comment: and nombre_usuario not like '%contra%' ?

Comment: Donde coloco eso?

Comment: no. no va a funcionar porque hay otro que dice contra y tambien te lo va a sacar. cual es la regla exacta por la cual esos no van?

Comment: Podrias cambiar la imagen por los datos que queres mostrar, y agregar a la pregunta la regla por la cual esos no van? asi como estan, la regla no es clara

Comment: Por ese campo no puede ser porque ellos pueden modificar sus nombres..

Comment: Sinceramente no esta claro lo que necesitas, debes aclarar mas lo que tienes y lo que quieres obtener, asi como una muestra de datos para un ejemplo y los PK y FK de las tablas implicadas. Tal y como esta la pregunta lo unico que podria decir es que aparenta haber un error de diseño de las tablas.